# Parameter in dynamical sql server query

Tags: sql-server

i have problem with passing parameters in my dynamical query. Here is the error message

> Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure WriteJobLog, Line 101 Error
>   writing job log: Line #90: [ERR]  #7: Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@LastId".

and my sql code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncReportServerFormatEntries]
    @SyncJobId varchar(50),
    @SyncJobStep varchar(50)=NULL, -- Sproc name will be used as a job step if not specified
    @SyncExecId int=NULL, -- Will be obtained from @SyncJobStep step execution if not specified
    @LastId BIGINT=NULL, -- Last transaction id to snyc, will be obtained from WarehouseMgmt.SyncSQLData if not specified
    @SyncObjectName VARCHAR(50) = 'WarehouseMgmt.FactReportServerExecutionLog'
AS
..........
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
        DECLARE @server nvarchar(255) = (SELECT [Value] FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncConfig] WHERE [Key] = 'ReportServerLinkedServer')
        DECLARE @database nvarchar(255) = (SELECT [Value] FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncConfig] WHERE [Key] = 'ReportServerDatabase')

        SET @sql='MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerFormatEntries] AS Target
        USING( 
                  SELECT CASE [Format]
                  WHEN ''RPL'' THEN ''View''
                  ELSE ''Export'' 
                  END [Name],
                  [Format] [OriginalFormatName],
                  LogEntryId 
                  FROM OPENQUERY('+@server+',
                  ''SELECT CASE [Format]
                  WHEN ''''RPL'''' THEN ''''View''''
                  ELSE ''''Export'''' 
                  END [Name],
                  [Format] [OriginalFormatName],
                  LogEntryId  
                  FROM '+@database+'.dbo.[ExecutionLogStorage] WHERE LogEntryId > @LastId AND [Parameters] IS NOT NULL '' )               

              ) AS Source
        ON Source.LogEntryId=Target.SourceOrigId
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT 
            (
                [Name],
                [OriginalFormatName],
                [SourceOrigId],
                SyncExecId
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                ISNULL(Source.[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                ISNULL(Source.[OriginalFormatName],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                Source.[LogEntryId],
                @SyncExecId
            )
            OUTPUT  
                ISNULL(Source.[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                ISNULL(Source.[OriginalFormatName],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                Source.[LogEntryId]
            INTO #NewReportServerFormatEntries;' 

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@LastId bigint,@SyncExecId int',@LastId,@SyncExecId;
```

Comment: Your error is in Procedure WriteJobLog you posted code from [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncReportServerFormatEntries]. Check line 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you'll get much benefit from passing parameters into dynamic SQL. Maybe try without the params?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncReportServerFormatEntries]
    @SyncJobId varchar(50),
    @SyncJobStep varchar(50)=NULL, -- Sproc name will be used as a job step if not specified
    @SyncExecId int=NULL, -- Will be obtained from @SyncJobStep step execution if not specified
    @LastId BIGINT=NULL, -- Last transaction id to snyc, will be obtained from WarehouseMgmt.SyncSQLData if not specified
    @SyncObjectName VARCHAR(50) = 'WarehouseMgmt.FactReportServerExecutionLog'
AS
..........
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
        DECLARE @server nvarchar(255) = (SELECT [Value] FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncConfig] WHERE [Key] = 'ReportServerLinkedServer')
        DECLARE @database nvarchar(255) = (SELECT [Value] FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[SyncConfig] WHERE [Key] = 'ReportServerDatabase')

        SET @sql='MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerFormatEntries] AS Target
        USING( 
                  SELECT CASE [Format]
                  WHEN ''RPL'' THEN ''View''
                  ELSE ''Export'' 
                  END [Name],
                  [Format] AS [OriginalFormatName],
                  LogEntryId 
                  FROM OPENQUERY('+@server+',
                  ''SELECT CASE [Format]
                  WHEN ''''RPL'''' THEN ''''View''''
                  ELSE ''''Export'''' 
                  END [Name],
                  [Format],
                  LogEntryId  
                  FROM '+@database+'.dbo.[ExecutionLogStorage] WHERE LogEntryId > ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LastId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'NULL') + ' AND [Parameters] IS NOT NULL '' )               

              ) AS Source
        ON Source.LogEntryId=Target.SourceOrigId
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT 
            (
                [Name],
                [OriginalFormatName],
                [SourceOrigId],
                SyncExecId
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                ISNULL(Source.[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                ISNULL(Source.[OriginalFormatName],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                Source.[LogEntryId],
                ' + ISNULL(CAST(@SyncExecId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'NULL') + '
            )
            OUTPUT  
                ISNULL(Source.[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                ISNULL(Source.[OriginalFormatName],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                Source.[LogEntryId]
            INTO #NewReportServerFormatEntries;' 

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Just be aware, I'm fairly sure that if casting NULL as VARCHAR, it'll null out your whole string. You want to use COALESCE surrounding the cast.

Comment: no this is not the solution. You cannot compare LogEntryId (is int) with LastId (cast into nvarchar), plus i must have @LastId BIGINT=NULL, at the begining

Comment: @user2171512 - the conversion to NVARCHAR is to generate the SQL. The comparison will compare numerically.

Comment: now i have this problem Error writing job log: Line #90: [ERR]  #3: Invalid column name 'Format'.

Comment: Rather than `[Format] [OriginalFormatName]` you possibly want something like `[OriginalFormatName] AS [Format]` -- but that's really dependent on your schema, that you haven't described in your question.

Comment: no i want Format from '+@database+'.dbo.[ExecutionLogStorage] and alias is OriginalFormatName, but if you just write [Format] AS [OriginalFormatName] is the same like before

Comment: @user2171512 - the format column doesn't exist. Is this deliberate? You reference a column called "Format" but present it as "OriginalFormatName" when you SELECT from the OPENQUERY staement. You have either missed a comma or you have missed an AS statement (not required but makes your intentions deliberate)

Comment: @user2171512 - I have just edited the original answer to what I believe it is supposed to be based on your recent comments. I think the alias in OPENQUERY is not needed so I took it out - you alias it further up the chain.

Comment: i have [Format] AS [OriginalFormatName], and also in openquery [Format] AS [OriginalFormatName], . Format colum is from FROM '+@database+'.dbo.[ExecutionLogStorage]

Comment: @user2171512 - that's your problem, by aliasing it you changed it's name, then you tried to use the original name (which no longer exists). I updated my original answer if you want to give it another try. If it doesn't work - we may need to leave the original AND the alias in the OPENQUERY query

Answer (score -2):

Since @LastId and @SyncExecId already come as parameters into this stored procedure, why don't you built the SQL statement concatenating the actual values ? Try this below. Note the direct concatenation of those parameters in the convert(varchar(250) phrase, where the reference to the parameters was present in your code earlier.

```
SET @sql='MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerFormatEntries] AS Target
        USING( 
                  SELECT CASE [Format]
                  WHEN ''RPL'' THEN ''View''
                  ELSE ''Export'' 
                  END [Name],
                  [Format] [OriginalFormatName],
                  LogEntryId 
                  FROM OPENQUERY('+@server+',
                  ''SELECT CASE [Format]
                  WHEN ''''RPL'''' THEN ''''View''''
                  ELSE ''''Export'''' 
                  END [Name],
                  [Format] [OriginalFormatName],
                  LogEntryId  
                  FROM '+@database+'.dbo.[ExecutionLogStorage] WHERE LogEntryId > ' + convert(varchar(250), @LastId) + ' AND [Parameters] IS NOT NULL '' )               

              ) AS Source
        ON Source.LogEntryId=Target.SourceOrigId
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT 
            (
                [Name],
                [OriginalFormatName],
                [SourceOrigId], ' + convert(varchar(250), @SyncExecId) + '
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                ISNULL(Source.[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                ISNULL(Source.[OriginalFormatName],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                Source.[LogEntryId], ' + convert(varchar(250), @SyncExecId) + '
            )
            OUTPUT  
                ISNULL(Source.[Name],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                ISNULL(Source.[OriginalFormatName],''<UNKNOWN>''),
                Source.[LogEntryId]
            INTO #NewReportServerFormatEntries;'
```

Comment: @TZHX : Oops, yes, we posted around the same time. I remember seeing that someone has answered, I had to frame the answer in Notepadd++ but a lizard must have entered my brain or something, didn't notice it's the same.